# Validate the invalid json input to avoid foreign-key constraint error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am doing a validation task for my Web API project. It exposes APIs to the front-end.  The front-end should input valid values in the json file, but sometimes, if the invalid values coming it cause exceptions in my project.

For example, `someId` cannot be `0` or other invalid values. Because if 0 was set to `someId`, the DB will yell the foreign key constraints error.

My solution to this is using the attribute validation

```cs
 [Range(1, 10, ErrorMessage = "{0} Values must be in range {1} to {2}")]
 public int? someId { get; set; }
```

So it will prevent the invalid values from UI. But the little hassle is I need to hard code the valid data range in each fields. So I am asking if it has a better solution than mine?

Comment: This post provides some reference to the problem. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296744/changing-validation-range-programmatically-mvc3-asp-net