# Date of birth custom range data annotation not working (breaking the page)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations

I have a custom data annotation validator to validate the date of birth to be between 150 years from today.

Here is my custom data annotation:

```
public class DateOfBirthRange : RangeAttribute
{
    public DateOfBirthRange()
        : base(typeof(DateTime), DateTime.Now.AddYears(-150).ToShortDateString(), DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()) { }
}
```

Using it like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "BirthDate is required.")]
[DisplayName("Birth Date")]
[DateOfBirthRange(ErrorMessage = "BirthDate must be between {1:M/d/yyyy} and {2:M/d/yyyy}")]
public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

This is a very strange problem because the error that I'm getting back has nothing to do with the data annotation. Its causing an error in my view here:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.JuniorSenior, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["seniority"], new { @class = "input-small" })%>
```

`ERROR: The ViewData item that has the key 'JuniorSenior' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.`

That error is strange because that part of the code is working perfectly fine. **What also makes this strange is that this error only occurs when the date entered is before 150 years from today.**  So that error only occurs when the date of birth validation fails. As I was debugging, I noticed that once I remove the custom data annotation, everything works fine and no error is encountered.

`So that leads me to assume the problem is in my data annotation.`

Here is my controller code in case you want to see what I'm trying to do.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Save(PatientModel patModel, FormCollection values)
        {
            // remove white space form text box fields
            patModel.FirstName = values["FirstName"].Trim();
            patModel.LastName = values["LastName"].Trim();
            patModel.Initials = values["Initials"].Trim();
            patModel.StreetAddress1 = values["StreetAddress1"].Trim();
            patModel.StreetAddress2 = values["StreetAddress2"].Trim();
            patModel.PostalCode = values["PostalCode"].Trim();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Pull the long form of the gender into the model.
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(values["genders"]))
                    {
                        patModel.Gender = values["genders"];
                    }
                    // Profile is valid, save it.
                    if (_Service.SaveProfile(Session["username"].ToString(), Session["password"].ToString(), patModel))
                        ViewData["SaveProfile"] = true;
                    else
                        ViewData["SaveProfile"] = false;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.Error("Function Name: Save  Message: " + ex.Message + "");
                }
            }
            IntializeSelectLists(patModel);
            if (patModel.Title == "Select")
                patModel.Title = "";
            if (patModel.JuniorSenior == "Select")
                patModel.JuniorSenior = "";
            return View("Index", patModel);
        }
```

My IntializeSelectLists function:

```
public void IntializeSelectLists(PatientModel pm)
        {
            seniority = new[] { "Select", "Jr.", "Sr." };
            List<SelectListItem> JuniorSenior = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (string item in seniority)
            {
                SelectListItem alb = new SelectListItem { Text = item, Value = item };
                JuniorSenior.Add(alb);
            }
            ViewData["seniority"] = JuniorSenior;
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of `m.JuniorSenior` when the exception is thrown?

Comment: m.JuniorSenior can be ("", "Jr.", "Sr.") depending on what the user selects. But like I said, the error only occurs when the date of birth is before 150 years from today. If the date is between 150 years from today, everything works fine.

Comment: Could you please show your POST controller action that receives the form submission?

Comment: When the exception is thrown, what is the exact value of `m.JuniorSenior`? And what is the value of `ViewData["seniority"]`

Comment: Thanks. You don't seem to be populating `ViewData["seniority"]` before returning the view. See my answer.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that code.

Comment: I have found a couple of other posts [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334293/dynamic-range-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-2) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334293/dynamic-range-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-2) that point to the RangeAttribute having some issues. It sure looks like its stomping on something.

Comment: You might want to ask yourself if there is any value in checking whether a date of birth is at most 150 years in the past, and why that is a better number than 149 years.

Comment: I answered my own question. I found what the problem was. Thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After bumping my head around I final found what the problem was.

In my `IntializeSelectLists()` I was populating the genders list right before the `JuniorSenior` list. As it turns out, the `pm.Gender` was returning null and therefore causing an exception.

The reason it was crashing at `m.JuniorSenior` was because I was displaying that before the `m.Gender`. So `m.JuniorSenior` was always null because the code didn't get to the point where it populated the `m.JuniorSenior`.

```
patModel.Gender = values["genders"].Trim();
```

I solved the problem by adding this in my `Save()`.

Thanks to everyone that took the time to help me :)